# Similarity learning for comparison of product description in R

Tags: r, machine-learning

Good afternoon, I would like to implement some sort of machine learning algorithm for the comparison of product description. I have two datasets, one with only the field DESCRIPTION and the other composed by two column, DESCRIPTION and CODE. I have something that looks like this:

```
MYDATA <- data.frame(DESCRIPTION = c("red chair 10 kg", "30 kg wood table", "150x200x100 cm 50 kg white bed"))

COMPARISON <- data.frame(DESCRIPTION = c("red armchair 50x100x50 cm 10 kg", "wood coffee table 30x50x80 cm 30 kg", "brown wood table 100x200x120 cm 30 kg"), CODICE = c("135tg67","aw56", "83776250"))
```

I wanted to use the function "stringsim" (I'm working with RStudio) which, with a high enough threshold, gave pretty nice results, that is finding the right match in the dataset COMPARISON, but I'm doing it for a school project it would be better if we used a machine learning algorithm, so that we could teach what is a correct match and what is not (in the example matching "red chair 10 kg" from MYDATA and "red armchair 50x100x50 cm 10 kg" from COMPARISON would be wrong, while matching "30 kg wood table" and "brown wood table 100x200x120 cm 30 kg" would be right).
I need to do this because in MYDATA I don't have a key to uniquely identify each record, I'm therefore looking for the matches in COMPARISON with the idea of then using the column CODE as the key in my original dataset.
Is it possible? And what algorithm would be best to use?

Comment: It remains unclear, what you intend to do with those two data.frames and what results you expect. Please clearify the question.

Comment: I'm really sorry, you are completely right. I have updated the question. =)